# How to change figsize for axes plots , subplots?

Tags: matplotlib

```
x =np.random.random_integers(10,400,20)
y = np.random.random_integers(1,600,20)
fig,ax = plt.subplots(ncols=3,nrows=2)
fig_for_all = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
ax[0,1].scatter(x,y,c='green', marker='*')
ax[0,2].scatter(y,x,c='red', marker = "8")
ax[1,0].bar(x,y)
ax[1,2].scatter(y,y*x, c='black', linewidth=3, marker='2')
ax[1,1].scatter(x,y, c = 'pink',marker = '3')
```

The figsize= 10,5 is not working, the subplots are staying small.

Comment: You create two figures. One with the subplots, and one that is 10x5 large. Instead, only create one figure and set the size for that single figure.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, thx u , i removed one with 10,5 but i dont know where to put the standard figure in?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56941236/4124317